# In how many ways can $5$ indistinguishable apples and $7$ indistinguishable oranges be arranged in a row if no two apples are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

There are 7 oranges and 5 apples that we have to put in a line. But no two apples should be put side by side. Find the number of ways we can form such a line if apples and oranges are indistinguishable.

Attempt:

-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-

So, $C_5^8=56$ ways

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Thanks. I asked this question before but I forgot to mention that they were indistinguishable.

Comment: Would the answer be same if we had 7 men and 5 women instead of apples and oranges? Because I found a similar question on stackexchange and it had a much different answer. Thanks

Comment: Only if the men are perfect clones of one another, and the same for the women. If the people are individually identifiable, you start with $\binom85$ ways to arrange the men amongst the women, and then you note that you can permute the men in $5!$ ways and the women in $7!$ ways, so you end up with a total of $$5!7!\binom85=\frac{5!7!8!}{3!5!}=\frac{7!8!}{3!}$$ arrangements.